# Facing a problem when i am making a setup of Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows

i am trying to make a setup of windows service.but when i was building the setup the output is like that..

```
------ Build started: Project: TwitterService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
TwitterService -> C:\Users\Globus-n2\Desktop\LatestTweetMati\TwitterService\bin\Debug\TwitterService.exe
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Setup' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup' completed ------
------ Build started: Project: Setup, Configuration: Debug ------
Building file 'C:\Users\Globus-n2\Desktop\LatestTweetMati\Setup\Debug\Setup.msi'...
Packaging file 'TwitterService.exe.config'...
Packaging file 'GlobusLib.dll'...
Packaging file 'TwitterService.exe'...
Packaging file 'GlobusTwitterLib.dll'...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

setup is failed i am  not getting any  error.i have tried to make a new copy but still problem remain.i have tried to   add those dll again but problem is not solved.can any one please help me to solve this problem.il really very thankful if any one try to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I'm assuming here that you are using Visual Studio to build this project)*

Try altering the output verbosity for the compilation. In Visual Studio, go to `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run` and change the value of the combo box labelled "MSBuild project build output verbosity". Setting it to `Detailed` or `Diagnostic` should give you more info in the output window, which will hopefully shed more light on what the problem might be.